# Spring controller's method could be blocked by sleep method call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

weird problem.I just wrote one controller like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyZM4.png)

Then i requested the api twice at the same time on my browser, but i found that one of the apis which is requested at the previous time blocked the other one?We could see the result like below:

```
**get locktime:Thu May 12 10:32:00 CST 2022current thread:http-nio-1111-exec-1:70**
```

```
**get locktime:Thu May 12 10:32:20 CST 2022current thread:http-nio-1111-exec-1:70**
```

diff seconds is 20 ?why weren't they print at the same time?

---

```
package com.shopping.redisson.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RestController
public class TestTController {

    @GetMapping("/test222")
    public String testT() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("get locktime:"+(new Date()).toString()+"current thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+":"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
        return (new Date()).toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: If you are not using same thread so it does not block your first request but in your log I can only see one thread that is working for two request.
Thread : http-nio-1111-exec-1

Comment: Are you using tomcat or similar server?

Comment: If you have configuration of one thread is responsible for all request then it is expected.

Comment: Thx for your comment, i have found the answer, because the problem is that google chrome could only send one  same request url at the same time.So the other request was been blocked.This is the case. @Gurkanİlleez

Answer (score 1):

Unless specified all Beans in `Spring` are `singleton` meaning only one instance is available for serving your requests. `RestController` is also be one of bean.

Since you have only one instance & as soon as you hit your controller method, there is 20 seconds delay to complete that execution.

That is reason even after you hit multiple requests at same time, other requests only got served after 20 seconds.

Reference
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s05.html